# java in-memory size optimization

Tags: java, memory, optimization

I'm writing some "big data" software that needs to hold a lot of data in memory. I wrote a prototype in c++ that works great. However the actual end-users typically code in Java so they've asked me to also write a java prototype.

I've done background reading on memory-footprint in java and some preliminary tests. For example, lets say I have this object

```
public class DataPoint{

    int cents, time, product_id, store_id;

    public DataPoint(int cents, int time, int product_id, int store_id){
    this.cents = cents;
    this.time = time;
    this.product_id = product_id;
    this.store_id = store_id;
    }
}
```

In C++ the sizeof this structure is 16 bytes, which makes sense. In Java we have to be indirect. If I create, e.g., 10m of these objects and use Runtime.totalMemory() - Runtime.freeMemory() before 
and after and then divide as appropriate I get approximately 36 bytes per structure. A ~2.4x memory difference is pretty nasty; its gonna get ugly when we try to hold hundreds of millions of DataPoints in memory.

I read somewhere that in cases like this in Java  its better to store the data as arrays -- essentially a column-based store rather than a row-based store. I think I understand this: the column-based way reduces the number of number of references, and perhaps the JVM can even pack the ints into 8-byte words intelligently.

What other tricks can I use for reducing the memory-footprint of what is essentially a memory block that has one very large dimension (millions/billions of datapoints) and one very small dimension (the O(1) number of columns/variables)?

Turns out storing the data as 4 int arrays used exactly 16 bytes per entry. The lesson: small objects have nasty proportional overhead in java.

Comment: totalMemory includes also the free memory, try to measure with totalMemory()-freeMemory()

Comment: 1st of all if you want a really accurate figure take a heap dump of your application and open that dump with something like Memory Analyzer (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to get an accurate figure.
2nd - whats the access pattern to this data? maybe you can gain more headroom by using some cache library that can page out unused portions to disk? say divide your points into arrays of 10K items and store these "blocks" in infinispan (http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/) or similar?

Comment: @Henry Good point! Measuring with  totalMemory()-freeMemory() gives a value of 36 bytes per structure. Better than 52, but still > 2x that of C++.

Comment: @radai The access pattern will be to hold all of it in memory at once so we can run simplified SQL-type queries that would make a normal SQL engine explode.

Comment: then yeah, dropping the OO pretense as much as possible and going with 4 giant int arrays is definitely going to save you some space - assumming you allocate all of it up front and dont have to deal with resizing and fragmentation. coupled with the flyweight pattern you might even try and pretend its OO :-)
also, if you'll be going arrays, can you maybe make sure you have under 2^16 products and stores loaded at any given moment and use a smaller primitive for store_id and product_id ? you could have a lookup table from your shorter temp_id to the real 32-bit one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't that straightforward to see how much memory your data structure takes in Java. totalMemory() shows the space allocated for vm which is larger than the actual usage. You could try using Java profiler that shows space-consumption of your data structures, they are quite easy to setup and run. One handy free tool is Java's own [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) that for example shows memory behaviour of your application, you will also learn a bit about how Java's GC works if you use it.

VisualVM screenshot showing performance footprint (image from http://visualvm.java.net/features.html):
[image]

You should also consider making the variables final if it's possible. It allows Java VM to optimize the code bit better (not sure if it saves space though).

Comment: Making them final is a good idea. Just tested it, doesn't change the memory footprint though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all an object in `Java` will always be slightly larger than a `C++` version since the object encapsulates runtime type information that enables you to do `instanceof` etc that is not possible in `C++`. Additionally it facilitates in the memory management you would have to manually do yourself, so you can also consider this part of your `C++` code as not part of the code base.

You could look into [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to reduce memory requirements so that you reuse the `DataPoints` (make the class [Immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)). I assume that if you have billions of points as you say some will probably be the same values.
I am sure others here will give some more concrete information on optimizing in memory space

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the value ranges you might be able to use smaller data types. Can you get away with using byte or short for some of the members?